# Retaining the state after Expand and collapse | Causing React state update error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, setstate

I have developed a upload functionality, upload component inside accordion. Now I want to retain the data/files that were uploaded in the system when the accordion is collapsed and expanded.

Now I am able to retain the files, but deleting them is throwing the error.

**Error**:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

**Design**

1. Parent component/ (Class component) [parentState]
2. Child component/Functional (upload) [maintains local state], sends data that is required by Parent component (Working)
3. To retain the state, after collapse and expand of accordion, Moved all the [local state] data to parent state through call back function.
4. On component did mount(functional component), took all the data and updated the loca state
5. Deleting the files (After opening and closing the accordion), getting the above error.

**CODE**

```
/** set the state locally from parent state 
 * component did mount
 */
useEffect(() => {
 
  
  if (parentState[`${field}acceptedFiles`]) {
    setAcceptedFiles([...parentState[`${field}acceptedFiles`]]);
  }
  if (parentState[`${field}rejectedFiles`]) {
    console.log('REJECTED FILES', parentState[`${field}rejectedFiles`]);
    setRejectedFiles([...parentState[`${field}rejectedFiles`]]);
  }

}, []);


/** maintain the state in parent state
 * this is used retain the state from parent state
 */
useEffect(() => {
  const afile = {
    [`${field}acceptedFiles`]: acceptedFiles
  };
  onChange(afile);
}, [acceptedFiles]);

useEffect(() => {
  const rfile = {
    [`${field}rejectedFiles`]: rejectedFiles
  };
  onChange(rfile);
}, [rejectedFiles]);



/** deleting the rejected files, removing them from UI */
const deleteRejectedFile = (uuid) => {
  setRejectedFiles((updatedRejectedFiles) => {
    return updatedRejectedFiles.filter(rejectedFile => rejectedFile.uuid !== uuid);
  });
}

/** deleting the accepted files, removing them from UI and removing from attachments
 * Send back uploadAttachments to parent state */
const deleteAcceptedFile = (uuid) => {
  setAcceptedFiles((updatedAcceptedFiles) => {
    return updatedAcceptedFiles.filter(acceptedFile => acceptedFile.uuid !== uuid);
  });
}

const handleRejectedFiles = (rejected, docTypeError) => {
  const files = rejected.map(file => {
    const uuid = getUUID();
    return {
    name: file.name,
    uuid,
    rightIconItems: {
      onIconClick: () => deleteRejectedFile(uuid)
    },
  }});
  setRejectedFiles([...rejectedFiles, ...files]);
}

const handleAcceptedFiles = (accepted) => {
  const files = accepted.map((file) => {
    const uuid = getUUID();
    const { PENDING, INFO } = constants;
    return {
      ...file,
      file: file,
      uuid,
      rightIconItems: {
        onIconClick: () => deleteAcceptedFile(uuid)
      }
    }
  })
  setAcceptedFiles([...acceptedFiles, ...files]);
}

const onFileSelected = (accepted, rejected) => {
  handleAcceptedFiles(accepted);
  handleRejectedFiles(rejected);
};

return (
  <DragAndDropContainer>
    <FileSelector 
      onFileSelected={onFileSelected}
      acceptedFiles={acceptedFiles}
      rejectedFiles={rejectedFiles}
    />
  </DragAndDropContainer>
);
```

**Design**
[image: dataflow]

**Updated the Error**

The error is in the delete function, as accordion is closed the component is unmounted, but `setState` is still pointing to its old reference [scope].

Is there a way to point the `setstate` to newly created component, instead of pointing to unmounted component without moving the state to parent function.

```
/** deleting the rejected files, removing them from UI */
const deleteRejectedFile = (uuid) => {
  setRejectedFiles((updatedRejectedFiles) => {
    return updatedRejectedFiles.filter(rejectedFile => rejectedFile.uuid !== uuid);
  });
}
```

Comment: You should not be copying the state into the child components when they mount. You should take the props and use them directly. Copying state around is usually a bad idea and the cause of many bugs now and in future. Truly "hoisting" state to a parent component means the child no longer keeps any copies of it around at all.

Comment: I think we also need to see a more full example, maybe in a codesandbox. I'd like to see your full component definitions and also where `deleteRejectedFile` and `deleteAcceptedFile` are called

Comment: @AdamThomas updated the code for the file selected. My assumptions is `delete` functions are pointing to the previous component data, which is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused due to referencing of the delete method. `deleteRejectedFile` and `deleteAcceptedFile` function's `setstate` methods were pointing to the component which was unmounted instead of pointing to the mounted component.

So I have created a new reference of the icon

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if (parentState[`${field}acceptedFiles`]) {
        const newAcceptedReferences = parentState[`${field}acceptedFiles`].map((accepted) => {
          const rightIconItems = {
            onIconClick: () => deleteAcceptedFile(accepted.uuid)
          };
          return {
            ...accepted,
            rightIconItems
          }
        });
        setAcceptedFiles(newAcceptedReferences);
      }
    
      if (parentState[`${field}rejectedFiles`]) {
        const newRejectedReferences = parentState[`${field}rejectedFiles`].map((rejected) => {
          const rightIconItems = {
            onIconClick: () => deleteRejectedFile(rejected.uuid)
          };
          return {
            ...rejected,
            rightIconItems
          }
        });
        setRejectedFiles(newRejectedReferences);
      }
    }, []);
```